# A parameter to differentiate multimodal density plots

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, density-function, kernel-smoothing, symmetry

I am trying to find a parameter that would summarize the shape of a density plot where:

1. an insight into the symmetry is given (not a priority); and
2. how regular/irregular the multi modals are

For example: I have plot 1 and plot 2 below: I want to a parameter that would differentiate between the them by specifically looking at the two points above. plot 2 shows a clear regular pattern, (4 maxima), where plot 1 has an overlapping peak and not very regular.

plot 1: [image]

plot 2: [image]

I tried looking at skewness (skewness() in R), but it is looking specifically into the symmetry. Any assistance is appreciated.

[EDIT 1] The data represents yeast populations with "equally spaced" stains. And the purpose of modeling is to see which stain concentrations give an equally spaced populations on our instrument data. So, if I generate 50+ stain combinations, I would like to see which are read by the instrument in a regular pattern (like plot 2)

Comment: Parameters such as skewness isn't good descriptors of multimodal distributions. Maybe look into mixture distributions, see the tag [tag:mixture-distribution] and try to some such! But better, tell us the purpose of modeling, and what your data represents. Without that we can only give some generic hints.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @kjetilbhalvorsen. Mixture distribution is a really helpful point.  The data represents yeast populations with "equally spaced" stains. And the purpose of modeling is to see which stain concentrations give an equally spaced populations on our instrument data.  So, if I generate 50+ stain combinations, I would like to see which are read by the instrument in a regular pattern (like plot 2)

Comment: Please add this extra information to the post as an edit. We prefer posts to be self-contained, and few people read comments!